# Missing some of the data when using ImportRange and Query function

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Notice the alphabet invoice not map over, is there a way to resolve it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itrpi.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShdiG.png)

Is this related to format error? I'm just trying to import all the data from another worksheet for analyzing purposes.

Comment: [This article](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/mixed-data-type-issue-in-query/) could be helpful to fix this query+mixed data type issues.

Answer (score 0):

QUERY only allows one type of data per column, the one that is majority in each one. For example, if in a column of 100 values, 60 are text, the other 40 numbers will be treated as text. The opposite case, when 60 values are numbers, the other 40 will return empty because those values can't be converted to numbers

There are some ways inside the QUERY to try to convert them, but in my experience I couldn't work well with them. What I've done is to transform the column into text between curly brackets. Something like this:

```
=QUERY({A:CX,INDEX(TO_TEXT(CY)),CZ:CZ},"Select * where Col1 is not null")
```

In case you have another locale:

```
=QUERY({A:CX\INDEX(TO_TEXT(CY))\CZ:CZ};"Select * where Col1 is not null")
```

Let me know if it's useful, or please share more specifications about your formula and data to apply it in your particular case